# Verilog state machine not as expected

Tags: verilog, simulation, flipflop, state-machines

I have a simple problem, but not able to debug. I am not a novice in Verilog, but this problem seems surreal and weird. I have tried all I could to debug, but still cannot figure it out, so sking for help.

I have the design of an FSM of traffic light controller) along with the testbench pasted here. The problem is state does not follow next_state for few clock cycles. I have tested with different testbenches but result is same. This is just a help I am doing for another person for his academic project. The design is

`timescale 1ns /1ns

```
// traffic light controller shell -- fill in the guts
// CSE140L  Summer II  2019
module traffic_light_controller(
            input clk,                          // 
            reset,                        // should force to all-red state
            e_left_sensor,
            e_str_sensor,
            w_left_sensor,
            w_str_sensor,           
            ns_sensor,
            output reg[1:0] e_left_light,     
            e_str_light,
            w_left_light,     
            w_str_light,            
            ns_light);


            parameter RED=0,YELLOW=1,GREEN=2;
            parameter     ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R=4'b0000,       

                                ES_G_WS_G_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R=4'b0001,
                                ES_Y_WS_Y_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R=4'b0010,

                                ES_G_WS_R_EL_G_WL_R_NS_R=4'b0011,
                                ES_Y_WS_R_EL_Y_WL_R_NS_R=4'b0100,

                                ES_R_WS_G_EL_R_WL_G_NS_R=4'b0101,
                                ES_R_WS_Y_EL_R_WL_Y_NS_R=4'b0110,

                                ES_R_WS_R_EL_G_WL_G_NS_R=4'b0111,
                                ES_R_WS_R_EL_Y_WL_Y_NS_R=4'b1000,

                                ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_G=4'b1001,
                                ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_Y=4'b1010;




    reg [3:0] state , next_state;

    reg [3:0] count_g_es_ws,count_g_es_el,count_g_ws_wl,count_g_el_wl,count_g_ns;           //Count till 10
    reg [1:0] count_y_es_ws,count_y_es_el,count_y_ws_wl,count_y_el_wl,count_y_ns;   

    reg ctr_en_es_ws_y,ctr_en_es_ws_g;
    reg ctr_en_es_el_y,ctr_en_es_el_g;
    reg ctr_en_ws_wl_y,ctr_en_ws_wl_g;
    reg ctr_en_el_wl_y,ctr_en_el_wl_g;
    reg ctr_en_ns_y,ctr_en_ns_g;

    //Sequential logic
    always@(posedge clk)
    begin
        if(reset==1'b1)
            state <= ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R;
        else
            state <= next_state;
    end

    //Logic for counter
    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset)
            count_g_es_ws <= 4'b0;
        else 
        begin
            if(ctr_en_es_ws_g)
                count_g_es_ws <= count_g_es_ws + 1'b1;
        end
    end

    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset)
            count_g_es_el <= 4'b0;
        else 
        begin
            if(ctr_en_es_el_g)
                count_g_es_el <= count_g_es_el + 1'b1;
        end
    end

    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset)
            count_g_ws_wl <= 4'b0;
        else 
        begin
            if(ctr_en_ws_wl_g)
                count_g_ws_wl <= count_g_ws_wl + 1'b1;
        end
    end

    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset)
            count_g_el_wl <= 4'b0;
        else 
        begin
            if(ctr_en_el_wl_g)
                count_g_el_wl <= count_g_el_wl + 1'b1;
        end
    end

    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset)
            count_g_ns  <= 4'b0;
        else 
        begin
           if(ctr_en_ns_g)
                count_g_ns <= count_g_ns + 1'b1;
        end
    end

    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset)
            count_y_es_ws <= 2'b0;
        else 
        begin
            if(ctr_en_es_ws_y)
                count_y_es_ws <= count_y_es_ws + 1'b1;
        end
    end

    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset)
            count_y_es_el <= 2'b0;
        else 
        begin
            if(ctr_en_es_el_y)
                count_y_es_el <= count_y_es_el + 1'b1;
        end
    end

    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset)
            count_y_ws_wl <= 2'b0;
        else 
        begin
            if(ctr_en_ws_wl_y)
                count_y_ws_wl <= count_y_ws_wl + 1'b1;
        end
    end

    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset)
            count_y_el_wl <= 2'b0;
        else 
        begin
            if(ctr_en_el_wl_y)
                count_y_el_wl <= count_y_el_wl + 1'b1;
        end
    end

    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset)
            count_y_ns  <= 2'b0;
        else 
        begin
           if(ctr_en_ns_y)
                count_y_ns <= count_y_ns + 1'b1;
        end
    end

    //Combinatonal logic
    always@(state,e_left_sensor,e_str_sensor,w_left_sensor,w_str_sensor,ns_sensor)
    begin
        next_state = 0;
        ctr_en_es_ws_y = 0;
        ctr_en_es_ws_g = 0;
        ctr_en_es_el_y = 0;
        ctr_en_es_el_g = 0;
        ctr_en_ws_wl_y = 0;
        ctr_en_ws_wl_g = 0;
        ctr_en_el_wl_y = 0;
        ctr_en_el_wl_g = 0;
        ctr_en_ns_y = 0;
        ctr_en_ns_g = 0;
        case(state)

            ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R :  begin
                                                    if({e_str_sensor,w_str_sensor,e_left_sensor,w_left_sensor,ns_sensor} == 5'b00000)
                                                    begin
                                                        next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R;
                                                    end
                                                    else 
                                                    begin
                                                       //Highest priority is straight EW
                                                        if(e_str_sensor)
                                                        begin
                                                            if(w_str_sensor)
                                                                next_state = ES_G_WS_G_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R;
                                                            else if(e_left_sensor)
                                                                next_state = ES_G_WS_R_EL_G_WL_R_NS_R;
                                                            else
                                                                next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R;
                                                        end
                                                        else if(w_str_sensor)
                                                        begin
                                                            if(w_left_sensor)
                                                                next_state = ES_R_WS_G_EL_R_WL_G_NS_R;
                                                            else
                                                                next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R;
                                                        end
                                                        else if(e_left_sensor)
                                                        begin
                                                            if(w_left_sensor)
                                                                next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_G_WL_G_NS_R;
                                                            else
                                                                next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R;
                                                        end
                                                        else
                                                            next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_G;
                                                    end
                                                end

            ES_G_WS_G_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R:begin
                                                ctr_en_es_ws_g = 1;
                                                if({e_str_sensor,w_str_sensor,e_left_sensor,w_left_sensor,ns_sensor} == 5'b11000)
                                                    next_state = ES_G_WS_G_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R;    //always remain GREEN-east and westbound through
                                                else if(e_left_sensor || w_left_sensor || ns_sensor)    
                                                begin
                                                   //count for 10 cycles
                                                    if(count_g_es_ws <= 9)
                                                        ctr_en_es_ws_g = 1;
                                                    else ctr_en_es_ws_g = 0;
                                                    next_state = ES_Y_WS_Y_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R;
                                                end
                                                else if({e_str_sensor,w_str_sensor,e_left_sensor,w_left_sensor,ns_sensor} == 5'b00000)
                                                begin
                                                    //count green for 5 cycles if no traffic, then go yellow
                                                    if(count_g_es_ws <= 4)
                                                        ctr_en_es_ws_g = 1;
                                                    else ctr_en_es_ws_g = 0;
                                                    next_state = ES_Y_WS_Y_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R;
                                                end
                                             end

            ES_Y_WS_Y_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R :begin
                                                ctr_en_es_ws_y = 1;
                                                if(count_y_es_ws <= 1)
                                                    ctr_en_es_ws_y = 1;
                                                else ctr_en_es_ws_g = 0;
                                                next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R;
                                             end

            ES_G_WS_R_EL_G_WL_R_NS_R: begin
                                                ctr_en_es_el_g = 1;
                                                if({e_str_sensor,w_str_sensor,e_left_sensor,w_left_sensor,ns_sensor} == 5'b10100)
                                                    next_state = ES_G_WS_R_EL_G_WL_R_NS_R;    
                                                else if(ns_sensor||w_left_sensor||w_str_sensor) 
                                                begin
                                                   //count for 10 cycles
                                                    if(count_g_es_el <= 9)
                                                        ctr_en_es_el_g = 1;
                                                    else ctr_en_es_el_g = 0;
                                                    next_state = ES_Y_WS_R_EL_Y_WL_R_NS_R;
                                                end
                                                else if({e_str_sensor,w_str_sensor,e_left_sensor,w_left_sensor,ns_sensor} == 5'b00000)
                                                begin
                                                    //count green for 5 cycles if no traffic, then go yellow
                                                    if(count_g_es_el <= 4)
                                                        ctr_en_es_el_g = 1;
                                                    else ctr_en_es_el_g = 0;
                                                    next_state = ES_Y_WS_R_EL_Y_WL_R_NS_R;
                                                end
                                             end

            ES_Y_WS_R_EL_Y_WL_R_NS_R :begin
                                                ctr_en_es_el_y = 1;
                                                if(count_y_es_el <= 1)
                                                    ctr_en_es_el_y = 1;
                                                else ctr_en_es_el_g = 0;
                                                next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R;
                                             end

            ES_R_WS_G_EL_R_WL_G_NS_R:begin
                                                ctr_en_ws_wl_g = 1;
                                                if({e_str_sensor,w_str_sensor,e_left_sensor,w_left_sensor,ns_sensor} == 5'b01010)
                                                    next_state = ES_R_WS_G_EL_R_WL_G_NS_R;    
                                                else if(e_str_sensor||e_left_sensor||ns_sensor)
                                                begin
                                                   //count for 10 cycles
                                                    if(count_g_ws_wl <= 9)
                                                        ctr_en_ws_wl_g = 1;
                                                    else ctr_en_ws_wl_g = 0;
                                                    next_state = ES_R_WS_Y_EL_R_WL_Y_NS_R;
                                                end
                                                else if({e_str_sensor,w_str_sensor,e_left_sensor,w_left_sensor,ns_sensor} == 5'b00000)
                                                begin
                                                    //count green for 5 cycles if no traffic, then go yellow
                                                    if(count_g_ws_wl <= 4)
                                                        ctr_en_ws_wl_g = 1;
                                                    else ctr_en_ws_wl_g = 0;
                                                    next_state = ES_R_WS_Y_EL_R_WL_Y_NS_R;
                                                end
                                             end


            ES_R_WS_Y_EL_R_WL_Y_NS_R:begin
                                                ctr_en_ws_wl_y = 1;
                                                if(count_y_ws_wl <= 1)
                                                    ctr_en_ws_wl_y = 1;
                                                else ctr_en_ws_wl_g = 0;
                                                next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R;
                                             end

            ES_R_WS_R_EL_G_WL_G_NS_R:begin
                                                ctr_en_el_wl_g = 1;
                                                if({e_str_sensor,w_str_sensor,e_left_sensor,w_left_sensor,ns_sensor} == 5'b00110)
                                                    next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_G_WL_G_NS_R;    
                                                else if(e_str_sensor||w_str_sensor||ns_sensor)
                                                begin
                                                   //count for 10 cycles
                                                    if(count_g_el_wl <= 9)
                                                        ctr_en_el_wl_g = 1;
                                                    else ctr_en_el_wl_g = 0;
                                                    next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_Y_WL_Y_NS_R;
                                                end
                                                else if({e_str_sensor,w_str_sensor,e_left_sensor,w_left_sensor,ns_sensor} == 5'b00000)
                                                begin
                                                    //count green for 5 cycles if no traffic, then go yellow
                                                    if(count_g_el_wl <= 4)
                                                        ctr_en_el_wl_g = 1;
                                                    else ctr_en_el_wl_g = 0;
                                                    next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_Y_WL_Y_NS_R;
                                                end
                                             end

            ES_R_WS_R_EL_Y_WL_Y_NS_R:begin
                                                ctr_en_el_wl_y = 1;
                                                if(count_y_el_wl <= 1)
                                                    ctr_en_el_wl_y = 1;
                                                else ctr_en_el_wl_g = 0;
                                                next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R;
                                             end

            ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_G:begin
                                                ctr_en_ns_g = 1;
                                                if({e_str_sensor,w_str_sensor,e_left_sensor,w_left_sensor,ns_sensor} == 5'b00001)
                                                    next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_G;    
                                                else if(e_str_sensor||w_str_sensor||e_left_sensor||w_left_sensor)
                                                begin
                                                   //count for 10 cycles
                                                    if(count_g_ns <= 9)
                                                        ctr_en_ns_g = 1;
                                                    else ctr_en_ns_g = 0;
                                                    next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_Y;
                                                end
                                                else if({e_str_sensor,w_str_sensor,e_left_sensor,w_left_sensor,ns_sensor} == 5'b00000)
                                                begin
                                                    //count green for 5 cycles if no traffic, then go yellow
                                                    if(count_g_ns <= 4)
                                                        ctr_en_ns_g = 1;
                                                    else ctr_en_ns_g = 0;
                                                    next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_Y;
                                                end
                                             end

            ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_Y:begin
                                                ctr_en_ns_y = 1;
                                                if(count_y_ns <= 1)
                                                    ctr_en_ns_y = 1;
                                                else ctr_en_ns_g = 0;
                                                next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R;
                                             end                                 


        endcase
    end

    //Combinational logic for output
    always@(state,e_left_sensor,e_str_sensor,w_left_sensor,w_str_sensor,ns_sensor)
    begin
        e_left_light = 0;
        e_str_light = 0;
        w_left_light = 0;
        w_str_light = 0;
        ns_light = 0;
        case(state)
            ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R: begin
                                                e_left_light=RED;     
                                                e_str_light=RED;
                                                w_left_light=RED;     
                                                w_str_light=RED;            
                                                ns_light=RED;
                                              end
            ES_G_WS_G_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R: begin
                                                e_left_light=RED;     
                                                e_str_light=GREEN;
                                                w_left_light=RED;     
                                                w_str_light=GREEN;          
                                                ns_light=RED;
                                              end                                 
            ES_Y_WS_Y_EL_R_WL_R_NS_R: begin
                                                e_left_light=RED;     
                                                e_str_light=YELLOW;
                                                w_left_light=RED;     
                                                w_str_light=YELLOW;         
                                                ns_light=RED;
                                              end
            ES_G_WS_R_EL_G_WL_R_NS_R: begin
                                                e_left_light=GREEN;     
                                                e_str_light=GREEN;
                                                w_left_light=RED;     
                                                w_str_light=RED;            
                                                ns_light=RED;
                                              end                                
            ES_Y_WS_R_EL_Y_WL_R_NS_R: begin
                                                e_left_light=YELLOW;     
                                                e_str_light=YELLOW;
                                                w_left_light=RED;     
                                                w_str_light=RED;            
                                                ns_light=RED;
                                              end
            ES_R_WS_G_EL_R_WL_G_NS_R: begin
                                                e_left_light=RED;     
                                                e_str_light=RED;
                                                w_left_light=GREEN;     
                                                w_str_light=GREEN;          
                                                ns_light=RED;
                                              end                                 
            ES_R_WS_Y_EL_R_WL_Y_NS_R: begin
                                                e_left_light=RED;     
                                                e_str_light=RED;
                                                w_left_light=YELLOW;     
                                                w_str_light=YELLOW;         
                                                ns_light=RED;
                                              end   
            ES_R_WS_R_EL_G_WL_G_NS_R: begin
                                                e_left_light=GREEN;     
                                                e_str_light=RED;
                                                w_left_light=GREEN;     
                                                w_str_light=RED;            
                                                ns_light=RED;
                                              end
            ES_R_WS_R_EL_Y_WL_Y_NS_R: begin
                                                e_left_light=YELLOW;     
                                                e_str_light=RED;
                                                w_left_light=YELLOW;     
                                                w_str_light=RED;            
                                                ns_light=RED;
                                              end
            ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_G: begin
                                                e_left_light=RED;     
                                                e_str_light=RED;
                                                w_left_light=RED;     
                                                w_str_light=RED;            
                                                ns_light=GREEN;
                                              end
            ES_R_WS_R_EL_R_WL_R_NS_Y: begin
                                                e_left_light=RED;     
                                                e_str_light=RED;
                                                w_left_light=RED;     
                                                w_str_light=RED;            
                                                ns_light=YELLOW;
                                              end   
            default:begin
                        e_left_light=RED;     
                        e_str_light=RED;
                        w_left_light=RED;     
                        w_str_light=RED;            
                        ns_light=RED;
                     end
        endcase
    end

endmodule
```

The testbench is here

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Company: 
// Engineer:
//
// Create Date:   15:05:44 05/26/2020
// Design Name:   traffic_light_controller
// Module Name:   C:/Users/Shankhadeep/Traffic_light/tb.v
// Project Name:  Traffic_light
// Target Device:  
// Tool versions:  
// Description: 
//
// Verilog Test Fixture created by ISE for module: traffic_light_controller
//
// Dependencies:
// 
// Revision:
// Revision 0.01 - File Created
// Additional Comments:
// 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module tb;

    // Inputs
    reg clk;
    reg reset;
    reg e_left_sensor;
    reg e_str_sensor;
    reg w_left_sensor;
    reg w_str_sensor;
    reg ns_sensor;

    // Outputs
    wire [1:0] e_left_light;
    wire [1:0] e_str_light;
    wire [1:0] w_left_light;
    wire [1:0] w_str_light;
    wire [1:0] ns_light;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    traffic_light_controller uut (
        .clk(clk), 
        .reset(reset), 
        .e_left_sensor(e_left_sensor), 
        .e_str_sensor(e_str_sensor), 
        .w_left_sensor(w_left_sensor), 
        .w_str_sensor(w_str_sensor), 
        .ns_sensor(ns_sensor), 
        .e_left_light(e_left_light), 
        .e_str_light(e_str_light), 
        .w_left_light(w_left_light), 
        .w_str_light(w_str_light), 
        .ns_light(ns_light)
    );

    always begin
  #5 clk = 1'b0;
  #5 clk = 1'b1;
  end

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs

        reset          = 1'b1;
  e_left_sensor = 1'b0;
  e_str_sensor  = 1'b0;
  w_left_sensor = 1'b0;
  w_str_sensor  = 1'b0;
  ns_sensor      = 1'b0;
  #20 reset    = 1'b0;
    #10;    

        #30 e_left_sensor       = 1'b1 ;
  #30 w_left_sensor = 1'b1 ;
  #60 e_left_sensor = 1'b0 ;
  #20 e_str_sensor  = 1'b1 ;
  #30 w_str_sensor  = 1'b1 ;
  #60 e_str_sensor  = 1'b0 ;
  #10 w_str_sensor  = 1'b0;
  #30 w_left_sensor = 1'b0;
  #200;

        // Add stimulus here

    end

endmodule
```

I cannot figure out why at 90 ns, state is 0111 and next_state is 0111 at the same cycle.
The behavior from 90ns to 160ns is uncanny.
For reference, I am sharing the screenshot of waveform

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You go to `0111` state when `w_left_sensor` gets high. Moreover, in that state you have following condition:

```
if({e_str_sensor,w_str_sensor,e_left_sensor,w_left_sensor,ns_sensor} == 5'b00110)
    next_state = ES_R_WS_R_EL_G_WL_G_NS_R;
```

This condition evaluates to TRUE, so your `next_state` is equal to the state you're already in. Thus, your waveform looks exactly as it should.

Comment: next_state going to 0111 is understandable, but then state should go to 0111 on the next cycle, why is it going in the same cycle?

Comment: @shaam drive your input signals at negative edge of clock and you will see that everything is ok.

Comment: unfortunately the testbench can't be changed it seems some academic constraints. anything that is missing in the RTL ?

Comment: It is intriguing that how state and next_state can change at the same cycle, not one cycle later!